# Send email using Mutt without authentication

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, attachment, mutt

I have an intranet SMTP server without authentication.

I'm trying to send an email using Mutt; I've configured it as below:

```
set from = ""
#set use_from = yes
#SMTP user auth
set smtp_url = "smtp://user@<ip-address-of-my-server>:25"
#set smtp_pass = "$imap_pass"
```

But when I try to send an email using this command:

```
mutt -s "Test message" my-username@mail.com < /root/testMsg.txt
```

I get this message:

```
SMTP server does not support authentication
Could not send the message.
```

I've tried different configuration, with and without user, ecc, but I only get errors.

My question: Is it possible to send an email using Mutt without authentication?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try with mailx and / or sendmail (most mail servers have sendmail command). if it works, then problem will be with mutt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you should omit the `user@` from your `smtp_url` setting.

I.e.:

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://<ip-address-of-my-server>:25"
```

Mutt's [documentation on *smtp_url*](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#smtp-url) says everything but the host name (or address) is optional on the right hand side of the URL.